# Smooth transistion of music notes using music processing

Tags: audio-recognition

I need advice regarding a small dataset of individual music notes played on a harmonica that I created a while ago. I want to build a system that reads notations in a text file and create realistic audio by combining audio files with the near-perfect transition of notes

What should I look into for reference or as a starting point for the project?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I had to provide a tag so I choose 'audio-recognition'. I do not want to perform classification.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to use your data as audio samples, and create a multi sample based Virtual Instrument. Here is a [tutorial in Reaper Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxEGphq0Gck). Then you can use [MIDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) as the control signal.